# How to configure Sublime text 2 to use my installed python libraries

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I just started using Sublime Text 2 and I can't seem to get it to work with most of the libraries I have installed for Python 2.7 for windows, every time I try to import them and run it, it gives me this message "C:\Python27\Python.exe: can't find '**main**' module in ''".

I tried configuring the Python.sublime-build but nothing I do to it seems to work, for reference this is what it has right now:

```
{
    "cmd": ["Python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

I'm learning to program and I've only used IDLE so far so I'm very new to Sublime, I'm most likely missing something, if you guys can help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: If you import the module you are looking for from promt, does that work?

Comment: I tried to import it every which way and gives me that error every time, tried even stuff like random and none get imported.

Comment: What he means is, go to the command prompt (`Start->Run->cmd`) then type `c:\python27\python.exe` and get the `>>>` prompt. If you type something like `import sys` what happens? What happens if you type `import mylib` or whatever the name of your favorite installed module is?

Comment: Ah I thought that's what he meant but I wasn't sure, sorry. Yes I tried that and the prompt runs everything smoothly, I just tried it again with a few different libs and they all worked.

Comment: I figured out what it was, turns out that unlike IDLE, Sublime doesn't like to import random libraries and what not unless you save your project first. Found out here while I was looking for something else http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9318

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a year late but for this kind of problem, I think you just test by running on a "untitled" file (which means you didn't save it under .py file). You have to save it then run it.

The point is sublime text will call the cmd, call python in command line and pass the python script file name to it. If you don't save the file, it's like calling python.exe to run on nothing.