# Unable to execute python script from command-line

Tags: python

I have sublime text 3 and python 3.6 on my windows 10 os.

I written the basic "Hello World!" program in sublime text 3 and saved it as "siri.py" on desktop.

I am trying to execute this on command line and it says, `python: can't open file 'siri.py': [Error 2] no such file or directory`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you need a __main__ call in your script, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Comment: Likely duplicate of [How to configure Sublime text 2 to use my installed python libraries] (https://stackoverflow.com/q/16945908/9200529). The answer there - that you must save your buffer before trying to run it - may help you.

Comment: @inbox please use the answer section below if you've found an answer.

Comment: @trebleCode in general, you *do not*. I'm not sure if this is something sublime-text specific, though.

Comment: Fair point @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: I couldn't execute python script from command line

Comment: @inboxoutbox can you open python's interactive interpreter, does `python` on the command line give you the `>>> ` prompt?

Comment: @davedwards, I downloaded pycharm and I am learning python there, the problem was "siri.py" is saved on desktop, however in command prompt the path was different. Thank you so much for the input everyone!

Comment: @inboxoutbox, so you got it working? hey, that's great news! cool, I just wanted to make sure so this question can get closed. thanks for replying, and cheers!

Comment: @davedwards, You are right,  It is working, thank you!